# Android background audio with a live audio stream

Tags: android, audio, android-service

I have come along in leaps and bound with my first android app in the last three days.  This is my last hurdle.  How do I get my app to run a background Service that will allow the audio to keep playing?  I have tried several examples I could find but they are based on playing a local (or streamed) mp3 file as opposed to a live (Icecast) mp3 stream.

Here's my code currently, everything works except background audio.

```
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageButton btn;
    private ImageView img;
    private boolean playPause;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = findViewById(R.id.playPause);
        img = findViewById(R.id.radioTower);

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                mp.reset();
                return false;
            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                //mp.start();
            }
        });
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!playPause) {
                    if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_rounded_pause_button);
                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_toweron);
                        img.setAlpha(1.0f);
                        playPause = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.pause();
                        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_play_button);
                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_toweroff);
                        img.setAlpha(0.3f);
                        playPause = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://bbcmedia.ic.llnwd.net/stream/bbcmedia_radio2_mf_p");
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use service to play audio file instant of activity.
here is simple code how to use media player in service.

```
public class MusicService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener {

    //region "member variable"
    boolean isServiceRunning = false;
    ArrayList<Song> PlayerList = new ArrayList<>();
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    int position = 0;
    MainActivity mainActivity;
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    int playingMood;
    private final static int MAX_VOLUME = 15;
    Toast toast;
    public static MusicService objService;
    //endregion

    //region "service method"


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        objService = this;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        try {
            isServiceRunning = true;

            if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
//                showNotification(false);
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION)) {
                playPrevious();
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION)) {
                play();

            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION)) {
                playNext();
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(
                    Constants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
                stop();
                stopForeground(true);
                stopSelf();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        isServiceRunning = false;
        objService = null;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }


    //returns the instance of the service
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public MusicService getServiceInstance() {
            return MusicService.this;
        }
    }

    public void registerClient(MainActivity activity) {
        mainActivity = activity;
    }
    //endregion


    //region "Media player"

    public void SongRequest() {
        try {
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = null;
            }

            //Handel UI on main activity
            mainActivity.showPlayer();
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mainActivity.updatePlayerUI();
            prepareMediaPlayer(PlayerList.get(position).getUrl());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    void showToast(String text) {
        if (toast != null)
            toast.cancel();
        toast = Toast.makeText(App.getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // try {
            mediaPlayer.start();
            mainActivity.checkPlaying(true);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        try {
            mainActivity.sentUpdateBroadcast(true);
            if (playingMood == 1) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
            if (playingMood == 2) {
                playNext();
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
        if (mainActivity != null)
            mainActivity.updateProgressBuffer(percent);
        if (percent == 1)
            mainActivity.showPlayer();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        try {
            Log.i("MediaPlayer", "error");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }




    void startPrepare(String url) {

        prepareMediaPlayer(url);

    }



    void prepareMediaPlayer(String url) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(MusicService.this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(MusicService.this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(MusicService.this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(MusicService.this);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //endregion

    //region "media player method"
    public boolean play() {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            switchButton();
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();

                return false;
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;

    }

    void switchButton() {

        mainActivity.checkPlaying(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying());
    }

    public void stop() {
        try {
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = null;
            }
            isServiceRunning = false;
            if (mainActivity != null) {
                mainActivity.ShowPlayer(0);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void playNext() {
        if (position < PlayerList.size() - 1) {
            position++;
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            SongRequest();
        }
    }


    public void playPrevious() {
        if (position > 0) {
            position--;
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            SongRequest();
        }
    }


    public void onError() {

    }


    public void onCompletion() {

    }


    public void onCleanMemory() {

    }


    public void initilizePlayerList(ArrayList<Song> list, int position) {
        this.PlayerList = list;
        this.position = position;
    }

    public boolean isplaying() {

        return mediaPlayer == null ? false : mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {

        return isServiceRunning;
    }

    public Song getCurrentSong() {
        if (PlayerList != null && PlayerList.size() != 0 && PlayerList.size() >= position) {
            return PlayerList.get(position);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer() {
        return mediaPlayer;
    }

    public void seekTo(int duration) {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(duration);
        }
    }

    public int getMood() {
        return playingMood;
    }

    public void setMood(int mood) {
        playingMood = mood;
    }

    public void setVolume(int soundVolume) {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            final float volume = (float) (1 - (Math.log(MAX_VOLUME - soundVolume) / Math.log(MAX_VOLUME)));
            mediaPlayer.setVolume(volume, volume);
        }
    }

    //endregion
}
```

you can start your service from activity like this.

```
   public void startMusicService() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MusicService.class);
        serviceIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        startService(serviceIntent);
        bindService(serviceIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
```

for stop service use this code

```
public void stopMusicService() {
    if (service != null) {
        try {
            service.stop();
            unbindService(mConnection);
            stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, service.getClass()));
            service = null;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, service.getClass()));
            service = null;
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

for bind service with activity use this

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                       IBinder _service) {

            MusicService.LocalBinder binder = (MusicService.LocalBinder) _service;
            service = binder.getServiceInstance(); //Get instance of your service!
            service.registerClient(MainActivity.this); //Activity register in the service as client for callabcks!
            if (listHolder != null) {
                initilizeSongsList(listHolder.list, listHolder.position);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {


        }
    };
```

where service is music service object in activity `MusicService service;`

Comment: I think you just exploded my brain.  I'll give it a try and see how I go.

Comment: Also the app just plays a single static URL, it will not change and cannot be changed by the user.

Comment: for play different song you need to pass song list to service. if you want to play single song every time then modify songRequest(String url) and pass url in method parameter service.songRequest(url) method and play that url instant of songList.

Comment: What are the required imports.  Auto Import seems to have missed quite a bit.

Comment: asim is this your personal code or is it available somewhere?  There seems to be many method calls to MainActivity that I don't have, some constants that I don't have and some UI elements

Comment: it is my own code and in this code i show communication between activity and service. for background play audio you need media player object in service and for handle media player from activity you need communication between service and activity. you can us broadcast receiver and service instance from binder to call service method.

Comment: As I'm just starting and stopping the stream I don't think I'd need to communicated between the activity and the Service, just start and stop it.  Also I keep getting Cannot resolve symbol with any use of `Constants`, I've even tried writing it from scratch and cannot the the `Constants` to work.

Comment: Constant is hard code value. you can use your own falgs.

Comment: I've got the background audio working perfectly now.  Thanks for that.  How do I access the running service from activity to check what state it's in (playing etc.)?

Comment: with service instance service = binder.getServiceInstance(); you can access service class variable and method.

Comment: I get the following error when trying to set `service = binder.getServiceInstace()` `Attempt to invoke virtual method ' ...$LocalBinder.getServiceInstance()' on a null object reference`

Comment: This is a very thorough and helpful example, as I am trying to learn how to implement a service can you link to any documentation that helped  you arrive at such good understanding?

Answer (score 2):

So this is the working service for a single live stream URL thanks to asim.

```
public class StreamService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener {
    public static final String ACTION_PLAY = "com.example.action.PLAY";
    private static final String STREAM_URL = "...";
    private static final String TEST_URL = "https://www.nasa.gov/mp3/586447main_JFKwechoosemoonspeech.mp3";

    MainActivity mainActivity;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
    WifiManager.WifiLock wifiLock;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public StreamService getServiceInstance() {
            return StreamService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_PLAY)) {
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
            mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            wifiLock = ((WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE))
                    .createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF, "mylock");
            wifiLock.acquire();
            try {
                // Set the stream URL location
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(TEST_URL);
                // prepareAsync must be called after setAudioStreamType and setOnPreparedListener
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        // ... react appropriately ...
        // The MediaPlayer has moved to the Error state, must be reset!
        return false;
    }

    void switchButton() {
        mainActivity.checkPlaying(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying());
    }

    public boolean play() {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            //switchButton();
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                return false;
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void stop() {
        try {
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /** Called when MediaPlayer is ready */
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
        //player.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if( wifiLock != null) wifiLock.release();
        if (mediaPlayer != null) mediaPlayer.release();
    }

    public void registerClient(MainActivity activity) {
        mainActivity = activity;
    }

    public boolean isplaying() {

        return mediaPlayer == null ? false : mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
    }
}
```

Which is implemented in the main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageButton btn;    // Play | Pause toggle button
    private ImageView img;      // Radio tower image that alternates between on and off
    StreamService service;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Bind the view buttons to local variables
        btn = findViewById(R.id.playPause);
        img = findViewById(R.id.radioTower);

        startStream();

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (service.isplaying()) {
                    Log.d("pause","Pause Playback");
                } else {
                    Log.d("play", "Start Playback");
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public void startStream() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StreamService.class);
        serviceIntent.setAction(StreamService.ACTION_PLAY);
        startService(serviceIntent);
        bindService(serviceIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    public void stopStream() {
        if (service != null) {
            try {
                service.stop();
                unbindService(mConnection);
                stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, service.getClass()));
                service = null;
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, service.getClass()));
                service = null;
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                       IBinder _service) {

            StreamService.LocalBinder binder = (StreamService.LocalBinder) _service;
            service = binder.getServiceInstance(); //Get instance of your service!
            service.registerClient(MainActivity.this); //Activity register in the service as client for callabcks!
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {

        }
    };
}
```

Service starts just fine, I just need to learn how to access the service object to implement the play pause functionality.